# Why is spectral sensivity of a photodiode expressed in A/W

Tags: optics, semiconductor-physics, electrical-engineering, electronics

Can someone explain me the meaning of the A/W unit of the photosensivity when reading a spectral response function of the wavelength characteristic of a photodiode?

Comment: I'm not an expert but my guess is that it refers to the current (in Ampère) produced per Watt of light incident on the photodiode.

Comment: Is http://electronics.stackexchange.com a better home for this question?

Comment: @Wouter: If this question isn't moved, then you should turn your "guess-comment" into a "fact-answer".

Comment: This looks like physics to me, being focused on the device-level. Electronics.stackexchange.com seems more like circuit-level. Sorry for the misplacing though, if it is indeed misplaced. Thanks Wouter for the answer.

Comment: I wrote up an answer as @KDN suggested, since it's more clear than a comment.

Answer (score 4):

The $A/W$ units refer to the current (in Ampère) produced per Watt of light incident on the photodiode. This current-production happens when the diode operates in the so-called photoconductive mode. Since your question wasn't on the inner workings of a photodiode, I won't expand on this, but [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photodiode) contains some more information if desired.